# Specify window painting region in WINAPI

Tags: c, winapi

I'm using one 3rd party SDK which get hwnd (window handle) and paints something on my window. And i want to specify window painting region (left, right, top, bottom) ? How it's possible to do it ? I'm found WINAPI function SetWindowRgn, but it's not good for me because this function specify whole window region. I need specify just window painting area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible to give this library an `HDC` instead of the window handle - you should do this.
That is, get the drawing DC for your window's client area (`GetDC`), create the needed clipping region, and set it (`SelectClipRgn`).

In case your library insists on accepting the window handle - I can propose the following solution:

Inside your window create **another** child window, set the appropriate region for it. And give the handle of **that** window to your library.

Comment: Thanks, I created another child window.

Answer (score 3):

SetWindowRgn() is exactly what you need. You can create your region from a rectangle using CreateRectRgn(). A good introduction to window regions can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/rgnguide.aspx).

Alternatively you can modify the non-client area of your window, but I would not recommend that, because it has several side-effects.